# Motherboard Compatability

Tags: mining, gpu

The amount of Video Cards a motherboard can support (if using powered risers) is only limited by the number of PCI-E slots, correct? I've found a board (MSI - B250 GAMING M3 ATX LGA1151 Motherboard) that has 2 PCI-E 16x and 4 PCI-E 1x. If I use powered risers there should be no issue right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily correct, though it may be correct in your situation. It appears some people have issues with fully populating the PCI-e slots, though it's unclear whether a BIOS update or reconfiguration would have helped.

I also recently read something on a review site that was testing a motherboard for fun that supported a ridiculous number of PCI-e slots (pretty sure it was more than 10). However, it refused to work when fully populated with AMD cards. All slots were usable when a few nVidia cards were used. Not clear whether this was an OS or hardware limit. Speaking of which, you may also wish to consider OS limits. I seem to recall encountering instances of people running into walls with certain versions of Windows 8 and 5+ GPUs.

I can't say for certain that all motherboards can support as many GPUs as they have PCI-e slots, but I can say that some configurations may involve tofurkey sacrifices and head-banging.

P.S. I'm not endorsing (or discouraging) this particular setup, but you should be aware of things like the potential for fire when dealing with high-power setups and equipment of questionable repute (I'm looking at you, powered risers of unknown origin).

Answer (score 0):

Well I've learned it the hard way.. but apparently, that particular board, MSI B250 Gaming M3 can support only 4 GPUs at the same time, despite there are 4 pci-e slots on it. 
See the notes under "Slots" section of the specification below:
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B250-GAMING-M3.html#productSpecification-section

• 2 x PCIe 3.0 x16 slots (supports x16/x4 mode)*
• 4 x PCIe 3.0 x1 slots

** The PCI_E4 slot will be unavailable when an M.2 SSD module has been installed in the M.2_2 slot.

** The PCI_E2 slot will be unavailable when an expansion card has been installed in the PCI_E5 slot.

** The PCI_E3 slot will be unavailable when an expansion card has been installed in the PCI_E6 slot.

So the answer is no, it is not only limited by the number of slots, there are also these kind of "not so clear" limitations.